# Why am I getting this "File exists" error trying to mount unmounted filesystem?

Tags: mount, btrfs, storage, raid1

Help greatly appreciated.

I have a hot swappable USB C 3.1 5 bay storage device ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VMK6ND7/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_taa_BETlFb399BQF4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VMK6ND7)) attached to a Debian box.

1st 2 bays are a 4tb raid 1 mirrored btrfs for redundancy
3rd device is a luks/DM-crypt backup drive that I swap with and identical 4th device for off-site backup.

True hot swapping is a no go with this host controller. What I have to do is shut down the 2 active mount points by unmounting (just regular, no lazy nor force). Works fine. I spin down, park, and sleep drives with hdparm, then for good measure remove devices from kernel (same thing happens if I skip this step). I turn off the device with the power button. Then I take out my drive.

The next day I bring the other drive back, and put it in, power on the drive, and the main 2 raid btrfs are reassigned new device blocks (sda to sdc, etc). I then try to mount the raid and get the "File exists" error like the filesystem is still mounted somewhere, but isn't. I've sent SIGHUP to smartd, removed devices from kernel, and scanned them back in to no avail.

Rebooting fixes it all, of course, but that isn't the Linux way for something like this. It's not like it's a kernel upgrade. It's just a little more advanced than swapping out a USB flash drive.

Thoughts greatly appreciated. Bash code below.

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk /srv/dev-disk-by-id-usb-External_USB3.0_DISK01_20170331000C3-0-1/
sdb           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk
sdc           8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /

# umount /dev/sda
# lsblk
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk
sdb           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk
sdc           8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /

# hdparm -y /dev/sd*
... (completes without error)
# echo 1 > /sys/block/sd*/device/delete
... (completes without error)
```

Here I power off the device and swap out the backup drives then power it back up.

```
# pkill -SIGHUP smartd
... (completes without error)

# lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk
sdd           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk
sde           8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /

# mount | grep sd # no /dev/sd* mounted anywhere
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)

# mount /dev/sdc /mnt/backup
mount: /mnt/backup: mount(2) system call failed: File exists
# 
# hdparm -y /dev/sd*
... (completes without error)
# echo 1 > /sys/block/sd*/device/delete
... (completes without error)
# pkill -SIGHUP smartd
# lsblk               
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk
sdd           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk
sde           8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
# mount /dev/sdc /mnt/backup
mount: /mnt/backup: mount(2) system call failed: File exists
```

```
# dmesg -T | tail -n40
[Fri Aug  7 23:39:08 2020] sd 1:0:0:2: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[Fri Aug  7 23:39:08 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:2 old:/dev/sdb new:/dev/sdd
[Fri Aug  7 23:39:08 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:2 old:/dev/sdb new:/dev/sdd
[Fri Aug  7 23:39:08 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:1 old:/dev/sda new:/dev/sdc
[Sat Aug  8 11:28:05 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:1 old:/dev/sda new:/dev/sdc
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sdb errs: wr 1, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 1, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sdb errs: wr 2, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 2, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sdb errs: wr 3, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 3, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sdb errs: wr 4, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 4, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sdb errs: wr 5, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS error (device sda): bdev /dev/sda errs: wr 5, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS: error (device sda) in btrfs_commit_transaction:2268: errno=-5 IO failure (Error while writing out transaction)
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS info (device sda): forced readonly
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS: error (device sda) in cleanup_transaction:1860: errno=-5 IO failure
[Sat Aug  8 18:59:57 2020] BTRFS info (device sda): delayed_refs has NO entry
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] usb 2-1: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Ugreen
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 093458F298A9
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] scsi host2: uas
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     KINGSTON  SA400M8120G     0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdf] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdf] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdf] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020]  sdf: sdf1
[Sun Aug  9 18:10:24 2020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
[Sun Aug  9 18:20:06 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:1 old:/dev/sda new:/dev/sdc
[Sun Aug  9 18:22:34 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:1 old:/dev/sda new:/dev/sdc
[Sun Aug  9 18:22:55 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:1 old:/dev/sda new:/dev/sdc
[Sun Aug  9 18:23:25 2020] BTRFS warning (device sda): duplicate device fsid:devid for f4cbf27f-8fb6-48be-87a3-d42023ab2eb7:1 old:/dev/sda new:/dev/sdc
```

For the strace, see https://pastebin.com/UBhccxxY

Comment: `mount | grep SD` is obviously wrong. Run `grep /dev/sd /proc/mounts` instead. Run `strace mount /mnt/backup` and add thelast few lines before the error message to your question. Is there anything relevant in `dmesg -T | tail -n 30`?

Comment: I just used `mount |  grep sd` to show no sd* of any type related to a block device. `cat /proc/mount` gives same result as `mount`. I've added the `strace` (btw, it matters not where the mount point is, it still gives the same error). Interesting is the result of `dmesg`. it seems btrfs (the processes) is tracking the drives even after unmounting and removing from the kernel. Results are added above. Btrfs may still be holding on the the filesystem somehow. No clue where to go from here.

Comment: What happens if you do not try to mount a block device but the filesystem UUID instead?

Comment: I wonder if it still shows up in `grep btrfs /proc/mounts`, `ls /sys/fs/btrfs/`, or even `grep btrfs /proc/[0-9]*/mounts`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because BTRFS caches some information about device filesystems and specifically UUIDs. When the BTRFS devices appeared at different device nodes, the kernel module got confused because the UUIDs no longer match it's idea of what they should be. If you run `btrfs device scan --forget` before trying to mount, it will cause the kernel to remove information about all stale filesystems. See [the btrfs device man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/btrfs-device.8.html) under the "scan" subcommand.